# asp.net ajax asyn. postback problem

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

There is a tab menu which was created by asp.net control. Now I'm changing this with a new tab menu I made  with javascript. There is an event on third tab and when i click the tab it's posting back with asp.net ajax as asyn. but it takes me to the first tab after postingback every time but I don't want to change the tab after this. it must be stay on the third tab just must be changed content that's all. How do I solve it?

thank you

Comment: Please provide more information especially a snippet of your codes. Kind of difficult to help you with the information you've given.

Comment: momently we forget the asp.net ajax tool. we have a button and we put an event, when we click it, it triggers so postback happens. And now we put a script manager and the button has an ajax event. If now we click the button it works as ajax so refresh doesn't happen. I have a tab menu I made with graphics and javascript and it has 3 tabs.(it works in update panel) when i click the third button an event triggers and get some information via ajax. I want it to stay on third menu after event. it takes me to the fist tab(as if the page refreshed). it's difficult to explain...

Answer (score 0):

If your home-made tabset is in the update panel, then it will be part of the partial update.  Your tab control needs to remember it's viewstate so that when it is rendered after a postback (or partial update) it will render with the right selected tab.  I suggest using a hidden field on the page that holds the value or index of the selected tab.  Then, when you go to render the tabset from a postback, you read from that hidden field and know what tab is selected and render as such.